# Multiple intelligent light switches?

Tags: lighting, smart-switch

For the sake of simplicity let’s talk about a single light which respond to 2 swtiches. I replaced the light for a smart lamp but it’s awkward because the regular switches keep getting in the way…

I was looking for something like a smart switch that can integrate with another switch in a way that turning the light off, either via “Alexa, turn off the lights” or “manually” would sync…

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 4):

That is fairly standard stuff.  There are smart lights that can be controlled from multiple switches and from Alexa.  We can't help you shop for specific ones but the *features* you are looking for are:

1. Truly smart lights -- they either have a "hub", or they are advertised as not requiring a hub and still able to integrate with Smart Home systems.
2. Your smart switches are able to be smart light controllers, as opposed to smartly controllable switches.  Some smart switches are not smart light controllers ... they LISTEN for commands from apps or other systems, but they control the lights in the traditional way by cutting power or reducing voltage.  Some smart switches have two modes: that one, and also one where they control smart lights smartly. If you want to control the lights from multiple controllers you cannot use a switch that cuts or manages power to the light.  You have to use switches that are aware of and control the smart lights smartly.

OR

2. The switches come in a "3 way" variety ... which allows you to use exactly two of them the way you want and also use an app.

To make your life more difficult, these distinctions are not always well documented in the marketing and advertising, and sometimes they are not even well documented in the documentation.   You may need some trial and error.

Comment: Other thing the OP may need to be concerned about is whether or not there's a neutral available for a switch, which may limit selection.

Answer (score 0):

**Best approach would make it opinion based.**

You can use

1. Smart bulbs such Philips Hue that you can control with wifi and apps
2. Smart switches that use wifi, zwave or zigbee (there are others, that I havent used)
3. Smart controllers that sit behind the switch (again zwave or zigbee)

These require

1. Direct connection to something like Alexa (you can use scenes on Alexa to do various things, but decisions are difficult)
2. Something on your desktop to program actions in them (this is very limited)
3. Something on your desktop that runs continuously to manage them (if you can leave your desktop on permanently)
4. A standalone server that manages them. (This is what I have)

I am not endorsing it, nor am I associated with it.  I am using Fibaro.  A small server for my holiday home and the most recent server at home.  You can retrofit to control almost anything electrical in your house.  You can add one device at a time.  It talks to multiple platforms - zwave, zibgee, Philips Hue etc.  It integrates with Alexa, Siri or Google Assistant.